Sci-fi/robot/alien movie in which a woman runs into an abandoned home to escape a four-legged robot
I woke up to the end of this movie, where a woman was running to escape from a four-legged robot figure. It chased her into an abandoned home in the woods-like. She discovered other bodies there that also had self-inflicted wounds. She was able to find a gun with which she eventually killed the robot. However, that alerted about 200 other robots to that home. She realized there was no way out; the robots started to invade the home. She then takes the gun and puts it to her head just before the robots reach the home. Then the credits roll.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, when you say "the robots started to invade the home but then the movie cuts off", do you mean that the movie literally ends like that and the credits start rolling?

Hi. So, as the rest of the robots are approaching the home.. the lady goes to the bathroom and sets up her phone or tablet to record her last words or say her final goodbyes to family I’m assuming. She then takes the gun and puts it to her head just before the robots reach the home. Then the credits roll.

I watched this movie this year a few weeks ago. I didn’t look 1980 or 1990 to me personally but I’m not sure how new it actually is.

Was it in black-and-white?

The description reminds me of a Black Mirror episode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalhead_(Black_Mirror)

The description reminds me of the Black Mirror episode Metalhead from 2017.
The Wikipedia article about the episode contains many details matching your description:

"Metalhead" is filmed in black and white, and it follows the plight of
Bella (Maxine Peake) trying to flee from robotic "dogs" after the
unexplained collapse of human society. The dogs were influenced by
Boston Dynamics' robots such as BigDog.


As the dog approaches, Bella leaps out and throws paint over its
visual sensor, then throws the paint can to the corner of the room to
distract it and hurries to the car. However, the car will not start,
so she turns on the radio and hides. As the dog investigates the
noise, Bella shoots it. The dog stabs her in the leg; she shoots it
again and it falls to the ground. The dog releases an air-burst shell,
showering Bella with tracker-embedded shrapnel.


In the bathroom mirror, Bella sees many trackers in her face. She
lifts a knife, but notices a tracker in her jugular vein. Bella speaks
into her walkie-talkie, unsure if she can be heard, saying goodbye to
her loved ones. As she puts the knife to her throat, the camera pans
out over the landscape, showing dogs approaching and investigating.

